# pd.merge does not gives any output and jupyter hangs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Considering 2 dataframes as below:

> **master_frame:**

```
permalink                  43195
name                       43195
homepage_url               41737
category_list              42931
status                     43195
country_code               43195
state_code                 42239
region                     42570
city                       42570
founded_at                 36668
company_permalink          43195
funding_round_permalink    43195
funding_round_type         43195
funding_round_code         15352
funded_at                  43195
raised_amount_usd          43195
_merge                     43195
```

and

> **english_speaking_countries**

```
country_name    61
country_code    61
```

While using pd.merge() to merge the master_frame with companies data, it is not giving any output. I have used the same code while merging rounds2 and companies dataframe. That worked fine.

I do have checked the values and the values are same for the country_code. I did checked this by using

```
master_frame[ master_frame["country_code"].isin(english_speaking_countries["country_code"])]
```

> I got the output of master df with around 35000 rows.

So the values do match.
But when I perform pd.merge the jupyter notebook hangs and gets restarted after around 2 minutes.
I did checked this on pycharm and pycharm also gets hanged.
To merge both dataframes, I have used :

```
pd.merge(
master_frame,
english_speaking_countries,
how="inner",
left_on=["country_code"],
right_on=["country_code"],
)
```

Comment: The result is probably too large fo jypiter.

Comment: 35k rows though? Could you share sample content of both data frames, so we can get idea about the actual size of your data frame?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

#Create master_frame dataframe.
a = ['permalink','name','homepage_url','category_list','status','country_code','state_code','region','city','founded_at',
     'company_permalink','funding_round_permalink','funding_round_type','funding_round_code','funded_at' ,'raised_amount_usd',
     '_merge']

b = [43195,43195,41737,42931,43195,43195,42239,42570,42570,36668,43195,43195,43195,15352,43195,43195,43195]

c = dict(zip(a,b))
print(c)
master_frame = pd.DataFrame(c,index=[0])
print(master_frame)

#Creaing english_speaking_countries data frame
a = ['country_name','country_code']
b = [61,61]
c = dict(zip(a,b))
english_speaking_countries = pd.DataFrame(c,index=[0])
print(english_speaking_countries)

#Merge both the data Frame.
df = master_frame.merge(english_speaking_countries,how='inner',left_on='country_code',right_on='country_code')
print(df)

#The output will be an empty dataFrame as there is no common values in the columns.
```

Comment: I suspect these numbers are counts of non-null content, rather than actual content of the dataframe. Also your answer is literally OP's attempt to solve it.